# Cannot connect to DisplayPort monitor (Debian)

Tags: debian, display, multiple-monitors, displayport

I am using Debian 12 and my monitors were working fine earlier. However, I left my computer for a bit and when I came back my primary monitor (connected via DisplayPort) was very dim (occasionally happens, I don't really know why) so I turned it off and back on.

However, that made my computer switch the primary monitor over to my side monitor. When I turn on the monitor, even if I set it to enabled and primary and drag it around in the Desktop Configuration settings panel, it still says there is no input detected and just goes to sleep, after which I can no longer drag it around in the settings because the OS thinks it's disconnected.

Rebooting does **not** fix the problem. When I start up my computer, everything appears on the primary monitor only, and the login screen and loading screen are mirrored on both monitors, but as soon as I finish logging in, my display settings take over and turn off the primary monitor.

At this point I'm about ready to just uninstall my entire operating system and just use Windows again, but I figured I'd see if anyone has any idea how to make my DisplayPort monitor actually turn on, stay on, and not be completely ignored my the operating system when I'm logged in. Thanks.

**Edit:** The other monitor is connected with HDMI. Unplugging it and restarting my primary monitor does allow me to use it instead which is better than before but if I plug the HDMI one back in, it immediately switches over and turns off the DisplayPort one and doesn't let me add it back as a second monitor via settings.

**Edit 2:** I disabled the DP monitor's auto-sleep mode so now it doesn't go to sleep, but the Display Configuration panel keeps constantly reloading the settings so I can't actually do anything because it's permanently resetting and any time I try to enable the main monitor it resets even faster if I change anything.

Answer (score -1):

Use <kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to bring up a list of monitor configurations and select Unify Outputs while both monitors are plugged in and on. This should make the monitors mirror each other. Now the DisplayPort monitor is also active, so you should be able to hit <kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> again and select "Extend to Left" (or "Extend to Right", depending on which way your monitors are set up, but it doesn't actually matter). Your monitors should now show different outputs. If they are the wrong way around, don't worry, just go back into Display Configuration and drag the monitors into the appropriate location.